# org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Exception

```
> Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Console Log

```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

>  * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command >'D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

>* Try:
>Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> * Exception is:
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1276)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$6$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$6$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitVa> lue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
>   ... 70 more
```

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "three.com.materialdesignexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile project(':securitycode')
}
```

This is Java module

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/libsvm.jar')
    compile files('libs/tesjeract.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
}
```

i tried everything i can searched online.please help me

Comment: Refer this question, it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: @Threezj : Check my answer below if it works for you.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your gradle with below dependencies :

**App dependencies :**

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':securitycode')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

**JAVA dependencies :**

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/tesjeract.jar')
    compile 'tw.edu.ntu.csie:libsvm:3.17'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
}
```

**Edited :**

Add below code to your gradle :

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Add below dependency and add `HttpCore` and `HttpClient` also.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

I have tried this dependencies with my projects.. 
And it worked..

Hope it will help you.!!

Thanks.!!

Comment: @Threezj : Remove dependencies for `httpclient` and `httpcore` because it is already included in `volley`..!!

Comment: Thank you  it work for me .but i make a  new Exception when i run the app.    > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jsoup/Connection$Base.class

Comment: @ Threezj : It means is that in your dependency `/Connection$Base.class` contained by more than one library..!!

Comment: @ Threezj: Check this answer also ->  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32557383/4018207

Comment: sorry i made a stupid mistake .but when i remove the dependencies for 'httpclient' and 'httpcore' ,i could not use the 'httpclient' and 'httpcore' package in java module

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to identify the error. But my suggestion:

In your project you enabled multidex, but you do not add the necessary multidex support library:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

See here: 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: Same error or is it a different one? Have you implemented multidex like described in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following question, now google has provided a way to resolve multidex problem,

[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue `Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`. I tried all the solutions which was given above but nothing solved. I tried deleting .gradle and gradle folder from my project. Still I faced the same issue. Then I check my XMl file where I used `app:` namespace but didn't import `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in my parent layout. After importing it resolved my issue.